# My laravel query isn't giving me my data and getting This page isn't working

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to get my query working and I'm hoping someone can check out my code to see where I'm going wrong.
What happens is that I get `This page isn't working` page and I don't get any errors in my log file or dev tools

Here is my query

```
$query = DB::connection('data')
            ->table('products')        
            ->leftJoin('categories', 'products.product_id', '=', 'categories.product_id')
            ->leftJoin('users', 'products.product_id', '=', 'users.product_id')
            ->select('products.product_id', 'categories.name', 'users.name')
            ->where('products.product_id', '=', 134)
            ->get();
```

Comment: Are you sure due to query your page is not working, because query looks fine.

Comment: I don't know. I know it works if I remove one of the left joins, but when I have both of the it doesn't

Comment: Then you have to check if there is some column mismatch in non working leftJoin.

Comment: I think it's working fine, because when I do the left join individually they work fine it's only when I have them together

Comment: This query tells me you don't know how to properly configure and use Eloquent relationships. This should be `Products::find(134)->with('categories')->with('users');`

Comment: you are taking name from 2 table try to give alias one of them

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake is in select you are trying to get name from 2 table try this

```
$query = DB::connection('data')
      ->table('products')        
      ->leftJoin('categories', 'products.product_id', '=', 'categories.product_id')
      ->leftJoin('users', 'products.product_id', '=', 'users.product_id')
      ->select('products.product_id', 'categories.name as category_name', 'users.name')
      ->where('products.product_id', '=', 134)
      ->get();
```